# In Excel, how can I avoid repeating a big part of the formula just to check if the return value is blank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a situation where I am referencing cells in a different worksheet and returning the values of cells from that worksheet. Although it works, I find my current method inefficient because I have to repeat the formula in the logical test part of the IF statement:

```
=IF(**EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA** <> "", **EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA**, "")
```

As you can see, I must repeat the main part of the formula just to check if it is blank first. If I do not do this, I get a zero in the cell (for blank values in the referenced worksheet). I'm looking for something more like:

```
=IF(**EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA** <> "", **RETURN VALUE**, "")
```

This looks cleaner to me because I won't have to repeat myself. Also, if we ever have to update the formula, I won't have to duplicate my changes to the repeated parts. **Is there a way to do this?**

The above is actually a simplified version of my problem, but the answer should get me where I need to go. My actual formula has nested IF statements checking along the way for blanks. For reference, here it is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SMALL(IF(ImportedData!$H$2:$H$1000>=DataFilters!$A$1,IF(ImportedData!$G$2:$G$1000=DataFilters!$A$15,ROW(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000)-ROW(ImportedData!A$2)+1)),ROWS(ImportedData!A$2:ImportedData!A2))<>"",IF(INDEX(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000,SMALL(IF(ImportedData!$H$2:$H$1000>=DataFilters!$A$1,IF(ImportedData!$G$2:$G$1000=DataFilters!$A$15,ROW(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000)-ROW(ImportedData!A$2)+1)),ROWS(ImportedData!A$2:ImportedData!A2)))<>"",INDEX(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000,SMALL(IF(ImportedData!$H$2:$H$1000>=DataFilters!$A$1,IF(ImportedData!$G$2:$G$1000=DataFilters!$A$15,ROW(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000)-ROW(ImportedData!A$2)+1)),ROWS(ImportedData!A$2:ImportedData!A2))),""),""),"")
```

Comment: Normally you introduce another column (possibly hidden) to store the result of `EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA`, and then you refer to that twice from the actual formula.

Comment: Also just a FWIW all the Row() counters do not need to be sheet specific: `ROW(ImportedData!A$2:A$1000)` gives the same answer as `ROW($2:$1000)` with less typing.

Comment: @GSerg - Thank you for your suggestion of adding helper columns. That is what I was leaning toward but, since each column has it's own references, I'm going to have to create multiple helper columns and then hide them. I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Since I am referencing rows on other sheets I thought I had to reference those sheets. Thank you for saving me the typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 2020, Excel includes the `LET` function. You can write:

```
=LET(ELCF,**EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA**,IF(ELCF <> "", ELCF, ""))
```

Where the three parameters are:

- the name you will use to refer to your calculation,
- the calculation itself, and
- the final formula using the calculation.

The function also allows for multiple names to be defined. The general syntax is:

```
=LET(name1, name_value1, calculation_or_name2, [name_value2, calculation_or_name3...])
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious solution is to use a helper column or cell. Just put `EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA` somewhere in your spreadsheet, then refer to that cell in your `IF` formula.

**Edit**

To avoid a helper column, here is a trick I've used on occasion:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(long_formula&""),"")
```

What this does is, concatenate the result of long formula with an empty string (which converts it to a string), then take the value of all that (which converts it back to a number if possible), then substitute any errors with a blank. (An error would occur if you attempt to take the value of something that's not numerical.)

*This will only work if you either have a numerical result or an empty result. It will fail if you have a text result.*

Comment: As I commented above: "Thank you for your suggestion of adding helper columns. That is what I was leaning toward but, since each column has it's own references, I'm going to have to create multiple helper columns and then hide them. I was hoping there was an easier way."

Comment: That's usually the best way. It's a bit of a nuisance, but much less of a nuisance than having to make every edit to a formula twice.

Comment: @user2597747, Please see my edit. Perhaps that will help you avoid helper columns.

Comment: The solution in your edit works great for numerical values. I'll use helper columns for text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the blank in the cell for further calulations or if-functions or Do you just dont want to see the 0s?

Second case:
Just use a number format for the column like

`0,00;-0,00;"";@`

First case:
Put the following code in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IfEmpty(LongFormula As String) As String
    If LongFormula = "" Then
        IfEmpty = ""
    Else
        IfEmpty = LongFormula
    End If
End Function
```

And use it in your worksheet like

```
=IfEmpty(**EXTREMELY LONG COMPLICATED FORMULA**)
```

Comment: The second case formatting option will not work when the referenced cell has a zero in it. I would need it to return the zero. The IfEmpty function solves it. Thanks.